# How to get mouseup outside of the component in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a **abc** component (part of the page). It has an event mouseup.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'abc-component'
})
@View({
    <div (mousedown)="mouseDown()" (mouseup)="mouseUp()"></div>
})
export class ScheduleComponent {
    mouseDown(){
        //doSomthing
    }
    mouseUp(){}
}
```

But the mouseup event can only trigger when the mouse inside of the `<div>`. How can I trigger the event even outside of the `<div>`?

Do I have to move `(mouseup)="mouseUp()"` to **app.ts** and then use something like `@Output` or `service` to let **app.ts** know? Is there any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add a global event target like

```ts
<div (window:mousedown)="mouseDown()" (window:mouseup)="mouseUp()"></div>
```

to listen to events globally. (`body` and `document` work as well).

This works of course also in the components class

```ts
@HostListener('window:mouseup', ['$event'])
mouseUp(event){}
```

Answer (score 7):

Inside the component its preferred to do as follow:

```
@HostListener('document:mouseup', ['$event'])
onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent) {
  ...
}
```

in this way you won't need to remove the event on `ngDestroy`

Answer (score 3):

A component can access events through the `window` and `document` objects. So you could set up an event listener in the component's constructor:

```
constructor() {
  document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", () => { 
    this.mouseup(); 
  });
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks, @MattScarpino, just need change `function() {}` to `() => {}`, otherwise, it cannot find `mouseup()`.

Comment: Does this need unsubscribing, or is it fine just like this in the constructor?

Answer (score 2):

A bit old but this might help somebody, you can use Observable.fromEvent too:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.mouseUpSubscription = Observable.fromEvent(window, "mouseup")
    .throttleTime(30) // throttle time in ms, optional
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.mouseUpHandler(res);
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.mouseUpSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @remborg, this is exactly what I needed. I tried using the accepted answer with @HostListener('window:mouseup', ['$event']) but that didn't work in my situation as it seems other things happen before that is called (tough to fully explain in a comment).